# Linking errors when trying to install Google signin

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google Sign In into my iOS Apps but while doing this i am getting below error.

Is there any solution to remove below errors?

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_inflate", referenced
>   from:
>         l002 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o)   "_deflate", referenced from:
>         l001 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o)   "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
>         l002 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o)   "*deflateInit2*", referenced from:
>         l001 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o)   "*inflateInit2*", referenced from:
>         l002 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o)   "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
>         l001 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I suggest you to use **Cocoapods** for installing the frameworks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fallow below steps

1. Go to Build settings / Linking / Other Linker Flags and add the "-ObjC" without the quotes. This assume you are using some "header

   file" to map Google framework and for Swift approach.
2. Go to Build Phases >Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other, the go to de /usr/lib directory and select "libz.dylib"
3. Compile

Answer (score 8):

This is very common error and doesn't have any specific solution. Although may be following workaround may help you:

> 1. If you are not using `cocoa-pods` use them to add new repos.
> 2. Check that you haven't imported `.m` instead of `.h`.
> 3. Check you haven't add two frameworks accidenlty.
> 4. Remove `-ObjC` Linker flag from `-otherLinkerFlags'
> 5. Sometimes using older version of sdk may solve the problem.
> 6. Navigate to `YourProject--Build Phases` and check you haven't added one file more than once. And also any `Link Binary and Libraries` are not missing from there.

[image]

Here is the Image Showing `OtherLinkerFlags`

[image: Other Linker Flag Discription]

For More Detail Refer to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html) Link

Good Luck... :)

Comment: @VikramPote I am glad it helps .. When I encountered this problem I stuck for 3 damn days ... And can't find the solution ... :(

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-ObjC` and `libz` solved my problem. However in my case I can't find `libz.dylib` in path `/usr/bin`. I used `libz.tbd` in the `iOS 9.3` folder instead and it also worked fine and dismissed those same errors.

[image: screenshot of adding the library]