# Getting error when using AFNetworking through cocoa pods in project

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, afnetworking

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CreateAcc2ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Not able to resolve this error .
Please help

Comment: this error occurs when some conflict in framework occurs. Although there is not any specific solution for this. you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626342/linking-errors-when-trying-to-install-google-signin/34626431#34626431

Answer (score -1):

First Check can you have not add afnetwork framwork in Your project Folder,
I think that it is take two times in your project.

If You have take it one time then remove afnetworking pods & reinstall.

Please check File declaration is not many time in target>build phases>compile source.

Comment: This is more of a comment, and doesn't belong in the answers section.